# Homescapes pieces randomness

Tags: homescapes

Some people are voting to close this question as a speculation about developer intent, but that's not what I'm asking for—I'm more asking for clarification on how a randomness system works, not why it is the way it is.

---

I mean, most of you know about Homescapes but I always had a question.

What is the level of randomness when pieces are coming down to the table? As you know, you link 3 or more pieces vertically or horizontally and then others come but how does that random works?

I mean, if it was 100% random, i guess you might have a change to never finish a level or so and that makes me think that there is somehow a controlled random.

Could I have clarification on how the system works?

Comment: why would this be closed as developer intent? It literally has nothing to do with that its asking about a mechanic

Comment: @Penguin I agree that this should not be closed. To be valid as developer intent, it must ask **Why is this the way it is,** but it is instead asking **What is the way it is?** a MUCH different question. This question should most definitely be kept open, and I've edited it to reflect this.